# About some definition of field, and proper ideal

Tags: ring-theory

I start reading Ring Theory arbitrarily. I have some confusion. I am assuming ring as commutative ring with unity. Once I read definition of Ideal of a ring then it is considered that $\langle 0\rangle$ is a proper ideal as an example. When I read definition of field then it is considered that a field is a ring which has no proper ideal.
But there are some books where zero ideal is considered as maximal ideal of field and field is considered as an example of local ring (unique maximal ideal). I am confused. Can you help me to remove my confusion?

Comment: I think the most widespread convention is this: an ideal is "proper" when it is not the whole ring, and "nontrivial" when it is not the whole ring or the zero ideal.  It varies by author, however.

Answer (score 1):

A field is a commutative ring with $1 \neq 0$ in which every non-zero element is a unit. This is equivalent to saying that a field is a commutative ring with $1 \neq 0$ which has no proper non-trivial ideals (that is one, in which $(0)$ is a maximal ideal).

That's the definition.

Comment: thank you . I understand where I did  mistake. Can you please suggest me , which book may be good for learning ring theory ?

Comment: Herstein's "Topics in Algebra" is a good one for a first course.